# python + sqlite insert variable into PRAGMA statement

Tags: python, sqlite

Basiclly I wish to use a string I have saved in a python variable as my parameter 'table-name' in "PRAGMA table_info(table-name);"

```
import sqlite3

connect = sqlite3.connect('exampleDB.sqlite')
cur = connect.cursor()

x = 'a string'

cur.execute("PRAGMA table_info(?)", (x,))
```

This was my first idea. Which did not work and neither did:

```
cur.execute("PRAGMA table_info(table) VALUES (?)", (x,))
```

Which was an idea I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360593/python-sqlite-insert-data-from-variables-into-table).

Just putting the variable in there like so:

```
cur.execute("PRAGMA table_info(x))
```

also proved fruitless.

Any ideas? This is my first time posting here so feel free to lecture me on how or where I should have posted this differently should you see fit.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You want to do the following:

```
cur.execute("PRAGMA table_info(" + x + ")")
```

Note, this is a duplicate of [Python sqlite3 string variable in execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880786/python-sqlite3-string-variable-in-execute)

Comment: This worked. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cur.execute("PRAGMA table_info({})".format(x))
```