# How do you safely pass values to SQLite PRAGMA statements in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-injection, sqlcipher

I'm currently writing an application in Python that stores its data in a SQLite database. I want the database file to be stored encrypted on disk, and I found the most common solution for doing this to be [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/). I added [sqlcipher3](https://github.com/coleifer/sqlcipher3) to my project to provide the DB-API, and got started. With SQLCipher, the database encryption key is provided in the form of a PRAGMA statement which must be provided before the first operation on the database is executed.

```sql
PRAGMA key='hunter2';  -- like this
```

When my program runs, it prompts the user for the database password. My concern is that since this is a source of user input, it's potentially vulnerable to SQL injection. For example, a naive way to provide the key might look something like this:

```py
from getpass import getpass
import sqlcipher3

con = sqlcipher3.connect(':memory:')
cur = con.cursor()
password = getpass('Password: ')
cur.execute(f"PRAGMA key='{password}';")

### do stuff with the unencrypted database here
```

If someone was to enter something like "`hunter2'; DROP TABLE secrets;--`" into the password prompt, the resulting SQL statement would look like this after substitution:

```sql
PRAGMA key='hunter2'; DROP TABLE secrets;--';
```

Typically, the solution to this problem is to use the DB-API's parameter substitution. From the [sqlite3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-placeholders-to-bind-values-in-sql-queries):

> An SQL statement may use one of two kinds of placeholders: question marks (qmark style) or named placeholders (named style). For the qmark style, *parameters* must be a sequence whose length must match the number of placeholders, or a `ProgrammingError` is raised. For the named style, *parameters* must be an instance of a `dict` (or a subclass), which must contain keys for all named parameters; any extra items are ignored. Here’s an example of both styles:
>
> ```py
> con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
> cur = con.execute("CREATE TABLE lang(name, first_appeared)")
>
> # This is the named style used with executemany():
> data = (
>     {"name": "C", "year": 1972},
>     {"name": "Fortran", "year": 1957},
>     {"name": "Python", "year": 1991},
>     {"name": "Go", "year": 2009},
> )
> cur.executemany("INSERT INTO lang VALUES(:name, :year)", data)
>
> # This is the qmark style used in a SELECT query:
> params = (1972,)
> cur.execute("SELECT * FROM lang WHERE first_appeared = ?", params)
> print(cur.fetchall())
> ```

This works as expected in the sample code from the docs, but when using placeholders in a PRAGMA statement, we get an `OperationalError` telling us there's a syntax error. This is the case for both types of parameter substitution.

```py
# these will both fail

cur.execute('PRAGMA key=?;', (password,))
cur.execute('PRAGMA key=:pass;', {'pass': password})
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. If we actually enter our malicious string at the password prompt, it won't work, producing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlcipher3.ProgrammingError: You can only execute one statement at a time.
```

So is the "naive" code from earlier safe? I'm not confident saying the answer is "yes" just because the *one* malicious string I could come up with didn't work, but there doesn't seem to be a better way of doing this. The answers to the only other person on here asking this question that I could find suggested equivalent solutions ([python + sqlite insert variable into PRAGMA statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51559620/11659424)). I'd also rather not use an ORM, especially if it's just for this one case. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.