# How to upload Tweets to an SQLite file prior to sentiment analysis?

Tags: python, sqlite, twitter, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I have code written that streams Twitter for a given hashtag and number of tweets, got that working, great. I need to upload the Tweets into an SQLite file before performing sentiment analysis on them. Currently they write straight to a CSV file and the sentiment analysis is being performed as the Tweets are stored. I have no real experience with SQL and am looking for help specifically with this part. I'll include all my code so you can see everything it's doing (the two parts where I need to write the SQL code I've put in between lines of *'s):

```
import csv
import re
import sys
import tweepy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from textblob import TextBlob
import sqlite3
global db
global cursor


class SentimentAnalysis: 

    def __init__(self):
        self.tweets = []
        self.tweetText = []
        # self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth)

    # Change access details below to point to own application
    def download_data(self):
        # authenticating
        consumerKey = '...............'
        consumerSecret = '..................'
        accessToken = '................'
        accessTokenSecret = '..................'
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
        auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
        api = tweepy.API(auth)

        # input for term to be searched and how many tweets to search
        searchTerm = input("Enter Keyword/Tag to search about: ")
        NoOfTerms = int(input("Enter how many tweets to search: "))

        # searching for tweets
        self.tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerm, lang="en").items(NoOfTerms)

        # Open/create a file to append data to
        csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')

        # Use csv writer
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

        # creating variables to store info
        polarity = 0
        positive = 0
        wpositive = 0
        spositive = 0
        negative = 0
        wnegative = 0
        snegative = 0
        neutral = 0

        # iterating through tweets fetched
        for tweet in self.tweets:
            # Append to temp so that we can store in csv later. I use encode UTF-8
            self.tweetText.append(self.clean_tweet(tweet.text).encode('utf-8'))
            # print (tweet.text.translate(non_bmp_map))    #print tweet's text
            analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
            # print(analysis.sentiment)  # print tweet's polarity
            polarity += analysis.sentiment.polarity  # adding up polarities to find the average later

            if analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0:  # adding reaction of how people are reacting to find average later
                neutral += 1
            elif 0 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 0.3:
                wpositive += 1
            elif 0.3 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 0.6:
                positive += 1
            elif 0.6 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 1:
                spositive += 1
            elif -0.3 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 0:
                wnegative += 1
            elif -0.6 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= -0.3:
                negative += 1
            elif -1 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= -0.6:
                snegative += 1

*****************************************************************
        # Write to csv and close csv file
        csvWriter.writerow(self.tweetText)
        # csvFile.close()  # delete this for the insert SQL code bit
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tweets ("+self.tweetText+")")
        db.commit()
*******************************************************************

        # finding average of how people are reacting
        positive = self.percentage(positive, NoOfTerms)
        wpositive = self.percentage(wpositive, NoOfTerms)
        spositive = self.percentage(spositive, NoOfTerms)
        negative = self.percentage(negative, NoOfTerms)
        wnegative = self.percentage(wnegative, NoOfTerms)
        snegative = self.percentage(snegative, NoOfTerms)
        neutral = self.percentage(neutral, NoOfTerms)

        # finding average reaction
        polarity = polarity / NoOfTerms

        # printing out data
        print("How people are reacting on " + searchTerm + " by analyzing " + str(NoOfTerms) + " tweets.")
        print()
        print("General Report: ")

        if polarity == 0:
            print("Neutral")
        elif 0 < polarity <= 0.3:
            print("Weakly Positive")
        elif 0.3 < polarity <= 0.6:
            print("Positive")
        elif 0.6 < polarity <= 1:
            print("Strongly Positive")
        elif -0.3 < polarity <= 0:
            print("Weakly Negative")
        elif -0.6 < polarity <= -0.3:
            print("Negative")
        elif -1 < polarity <= -0.6:
            print("Strongly Negative")

        print()
        print("Detailed Report: ")
        print(str(positive) + "% people thought it was positive")
        print(str(wpositive) + "% people thought it was weakly positive")
        print(str(spositive) + "% people thought it was strongly positive")
        print(str(negative) + "% people thought it was negative")
        print(str(wnegative) + "% people thought it was weakly negative")
        print(str(snegative) + "% people thought it was strongly negative")
        print(str(neutral) + "% people thought it was neutral")

        self.plotPieChart(positive, wpositive, spositive, negative, wnegative, snegative, neutral, searchTerm,
                          NoOfTerms)

    def clean_tweet(self, tweet):
        # Remove links, special characters, etc., from tweet
        return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t]) | (\w +:\ / \ / \S +)", " ", tweet).split())

    # function to calculate percentage
    def percentage(self, part, whole):
        temp = 100 * float(part) / float(whole)
        return format(temp, '.2f')

    def plotPieChart(self, positive, wpositive, spositive, negative, wnegative, snegative, neutral, searchTerm, noOfSearchTerms):
        labels = ['Positive [' + str(positive) + '%]', 'Weakly Positive [' + str(wpositive) + '%]','Strongly Positive [' + str(spositive) + '%]', 'Neutral [' + str(neutral) + '%]',
                  'Negative [' + str(negative) + '%]', 'Weakly Negative [' + str(wnegative) + '%]', 'Strongly Negative [' + str(snegative) + '%]']
        sizes = [positive, wpositive, spositive, neutral, negative, wnegative, snegative]
        colors = ['yellowgreen','lightgreen','darkgreen', 'gold', 'red','lightsalmon','darkred']
        patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, startangle=90)
        plt.legend(patches, labels, loc="best")
        plt.title('How people are reacting on ' + searchTerm + ' by analyzing ' + str(noOfSearchTerms) + ' Tweets.')
        plt.axis('equal')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
*******************************************************************
    def db_init(self):
        # create SQL table bit here
        db = sqlite.connect('tweets.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE tweets..")
        db.commit()
*********************************************************************

if __name__== "__main__":
    # sa.db_init()
    sa = SentimentAnalysis()
    sa.download_data()
```

Comment: Have you read the python docs for [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)? It seems the first example may help you

Comment: It is helpful but I don't understand how I set what columns my table would have. Will Tweepy know to split the data into the amount of columns I declare and actually put the relevant data in these columns?

Comment: The table definition (including columns and data types) is defined in the `CREATE TABLE` statement. There are also tools to help you create a table definition without writing SQL code.   For inserting the data, there are many resources for how to do this properly, including tutorials and Stackoverflow questions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360593/python-sqlite-insert-data-from-variables-into-table

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand what I'm asking for help with. I know there are resources and tools elsewhere online but I'm having trouble writing the actual code and was looking for pointers with that, not links to similar queries. The question you've linked me isn't really relevant to what I'm doing, guess I'll just keep trawling other resources.

Comment: In my understanding you are having trouble getting started with using SQLite in Python.  I am encouraging you to look at other resources as you are attempting to use SQLite in what seems to be a very well documented and typical use case, and existing resources should be more than adequate.  I don't see your question as directly answerable unless you first show some effort to try to implement SQLite databasing as seen in the docs or other tutorials, and identify a specific problem you are having.