# Updating a Table by using Sqlite3 Module in Python

Tags: python

I am working on a project where i need to update the password column of a user table pointing userid as the primary key, whenever the user reset his/her password. I am passing username and password to update_table function based on the values entered by the user from console and below is my code snippet -

```
def sql_update_table(conn, username, reset_password):
    c = conn.cursor()
    #value = (username, reset_password)
    #c.execute('''UPDATE user SET password = ? WHERE userid = ? ''', value)
    c.execute('''UPDATE user SET password = reset_password WHERE userid = username''')
    conn.commit()
```

I tried both case passing values with a tuple as mentioned in # and directly as mentioned without a #. However, for first case, there is no error but the table is not getting updated with the new value of password and for later one i am getting below error -

sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: reset_password

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python + sqlite, insert data from variables into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360593/python-sqlite-insert-data-from-variables-into-table)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try replacing

```
c.execute('''UPDATE user SET password = reset_password WHERE userid = username''')
```

with

```
c.execute('''UPDATE user SET password = ? WHERE userid = ? ''', (username,reset_password))
```

Comment: Thank you Bindu for your reply. However, I have tried that as well as below. Table is not getting updated.

value = (username, reset_password)
c.execute('''UPDATE user SET password = ? WHERE userid = ? ''', value)

Comment: while printing value, i am getting the updated values in a Tuple format but not sure why its not getting updated in Table

Comment: @SameerRanjanSahoo value should be enclosed in parenthesis. please give a try with this c.execute('''UPDATE user SET password = ? WHERE userid = ? ''', (username,reset_password))

Comment: Ok, I have tried. Got same result as before. Table is not updated.