# How do I resolve the values issue?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm having a problem running the SQLite3 DB queries. Following is my code:

```
    # create a database

    conn = sqlite3.connect('Bakery.db')

    # Create cursor

    c = conn.cursor()

    #c.execute("""CREATE TABLE stock (
    #        Item_ID INTEGER 
    #        ItemName TEXT
    #        Item_Price INTEGER
    #        Item_Category TEXT 
    #        Stock_Left INTEGER
    #        Stock_Sold INTEGER
    #        )""")

    c.execute("INSERT INTO stock VALUES ('00', 'Fudge Cake', '500', 'Cakes', '3', '0')")

    c.execute("INSERT INTO stock VALUES ('11', 'Ice Cake', '500', 'Cakes', '3', '0')")

    c.execute("INSERT INTO stock VALUES ('22', 'Small Brownie', '100', 'Brownies', '3', '0')")

    c.execute("INSERT INTO stock VALUES ('33', 'Big Brownie', '200', 'Brownies', '3', '0')")

    conn.commit()

    conn.close()
```

It gives an error that the stock table has only 1 column and 6 values were supplied.

Comment: (1) The shown table creation statement wouldn't work without commas between column definitions. (2) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `,` between columns names when creating it. The code to create the table should be:

```py
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE stock (
            Item_ID INTEGER, 
            ItemName TEXT,
            Item_Price INTEGER,
            Item_Category TEXT,
            Stock_Left INTEGER,
            Stock_Sold INTEGER
            )""")
```

Comment: And how should I put all values? VALUES ('00', 'Fudge Cake', '500', 'Cakes', '3', '0'), ('11', 'Ice Cake', '500', 'Cakes', '3', '0') like this??

Comment: The insert code was right `c.execute("INSERT INTO stock VALUES ('00', 'Fudge Cake', '500', 'Cakes', '3', '0')")`. You can make a for loop to insert values in a more efficient way. Example:
```for i in range(10):
     c.execute("INSERT INTO stock VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",(item_id, item_name, item_price, item_category, stock_left, stock_sold))
```

.The `?` will be replaced for the values of the variables `(item_id, item_name, item_price, item_category, stock_left, stock_sold)` according to the order of the columns. Sorry for my bad english, let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks for the help and I'll surely let you know.

Comment: This link may be helpful also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360593/python-sqlite-insert-data-from-variables-into-table

Comment: Glad to hear that! Please accept my answer clicking in the check mark beside it if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add column names after "stock" word, for example:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO stock(columnonename,columntwoname,columnthreename,columnfourname,columnfivename,columnsixname) VALUES ('00', 'Fudge Cake', '500', 'Cakes', '3', '0')")
```