# OperationalError: near "['Date']": syntax error

Tags: python

Basically I am reading a .csv file and inserting the values into  the db.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('att.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''create table cardswipe1 ('date','time','cardid')''')
cs = pd.read_csv('tst.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
x = cs.iloc[:,2:-2]
for rows in x:
cur.execute("insert into cardswipe1 values (x['Date'], x['Time'], x['CardID'])")

Data:
Date      Time           CardID
0    18-12-2017  11:56:59  '00064
1    18-12-2017  14:30:01  '00344
2    18-12-2017  14:30:02  '00031
```

I cant figure out why the below error is appearing, appreciate correction

*OperationalError: near "['Date']": syntax error*

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python + sqlite, insert data from variables into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360593/python-sqlite-insert-data-from-variables-into-table)

Comment: @buran you will note that its not physical input but multi insert in a loop, therefore it does not solve my issue

Comment: The point is you need to use parametrized query (first argument in `execute()`) and pass the values you read in a loop as tuple (second argument in `execute()`).  There is also option for `executemany()`

Comment: @buran im new at this, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sqlite3
import csv
conn = sqlite3.connect('att.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''create table cardswipe1 ('date','time','cardid')''')
with open('sample.txt') as f:
    rdr = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in rdr:
        cur.execute("insert into cardswipe1 (date, time, cardid) values (?, ?, ?)",
        (row['Date'], row['Time'], row['CardID']))
conn.commit() # you need to commit changes
```

alternatively:

```
import sqlite3
import csv
conn = sqlite3.connect('att2.db')
with open('sample.txt') as f:
    rdr = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = [(row['Date'], row['Time'], row['CardID']) for row in rdr]
with conn: # using with context manager commit() is executed automaticaly
    conn.execute('''create table cardswipe1 ('date','time','cardid')''')
    conn.executemany("insert into cardswipe1 (date, time, cardid) values (?, ?, ?)", data)
```

Because you work with sort of "trusted" data, simple f-string or string formatting would have also worked, but better stick to best practice to use parametrized query. As stated [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html):

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python
> variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string
> operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program
> vulnerable to an SQL injection attack (see https://xkcd.com/327/ for
> humorous example of what can go wrong).
>
> Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put ? as a
> placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple
> of values as the second argument to the cursor’s execute() method.

Also, I changed to using csv, instead of pandas. You didn't use `pandas.to_sql`. Also, note I have added `conn.commit()` in the first snippet and used `with` context manager in the second.

If you decide to stick to `pandas` - instead of iterating over rows, use [`DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
conn = sqlite3.connect('att3.db')
conn.execute('''create table cardswipe1 ('date','time','cardid')''')
df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt', dtype={'CardID':str})
df.to_sql('cardswipe1', con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

If you are OK with headers in the file, there is no need to create the table in sqlite3, DataFrame.to_sql will create table with column names as in the df.

This is `sqmple.txt` I used:

```
Date,Time,CardID
18-12-2017,11:56:59,00064
18-12-2017,14:30:01,00344
18-12-2017,14:30:02,00031
```

Comment: dataframe to sql worked perfectly...

Thank you

Comment: This dataframe to sql is on SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Not sure what you ask. It is not - you don't use SQLAlchemy as far as I know from what you show,

Comment: the link: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html you provided said sqlalchemy also so got confused. Anyway, I added headers to the csv and inserted into db

Comment: `con` parameter has to be either `sqlite3.Connection` object like in your case or SQLAlchemy `engine` for other DBs like MySQL, MSSQL, etc (it could also be sqlite3 too). But it will not work if you just pass connection to MySQL